# Pages in Wordpress won't enqueue child style correctly

Tags: css, wordpress

I manage to enqueue the child stylesheet correctly on the HOME page by following the [codex:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

```
<?php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent_style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style, 'photobox', 'default', 'bootstrap', 'enigma-theme' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

And I get the following output, with 'child-style' at the end, which is what I want:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"                        href="http://.../enigma-child/style.css"                type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='parent_style-css'  href='http://.../enigma/style.css?ver=4.4.2'            type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='photobox-css'      href='http://.../enigma/css/photobox.css?ver=4.4.2'     type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='default-css'       href='http://.../enigma/css/default.css?ver=4.4.2'      type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'     href='http://.../enigma/css/bootstrap.css?ver=4.4.2'    type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='enigma-theme-css'  href='http://.../enigma/css/enigma-theme.css?ver=4.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'   href='http://.../enigma-child/style.css?ver=4.4.2'      type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Although, the first stylesheet creates redundancy, that is not so important now. So it works fine for my Home page. However, when I load the other pages, the stylesheet does not load at the end. Actually, 'child-style' is not enqueued at all. I know theme_enqueue_styles() runs because it names the parent style for 'parent_style'.

In case it is relevant, here is the start of my child style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: enigma child
Theme URI: https://weblizar.com/
Description: This is a child of enigma
Template: enigma
Version: 0.1
*/
```

So in short, my question is why does my child enqueue last on my front page, but not on any other pages?

EDIT: As I still do not know how to solve this, I have made a quick fix that I am not happy with. I copied the header.php to my child theme and manually wrote in the stylesheet last in the head tag:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../enigma-child/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" /><!--LE: Quick fix-->
</head>
```

This is probably a bad solution which will backfire one day, but it will have to do until I get a better understanding. With this change, my entry to functions.php becomes obsolete.

Comment: It sounds like theme_enqueue_styles() is **not** being executed on the other pages. I don't quite understand why you think it is? Are you sure that wp_head() is in the head of the templates for each page?

Comment: If I comment out theme_enqueue_styles() from my functions.php then there is no stylesheet with the id 'parent-style.' Thus I assume it is executed. And this also means that wp_head() is in the templates for the other pages?